# Trying to display a different quote each time a button is pressed in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Since I'm new to Xamarin, this may be a stupid question but how to I get my quote to be displayed on the screen when it is referenced by the second **label object**. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with my **Text property binding** but I'm not sure how to change it in either my XAML file or my C# file.

Also, I want to make sure that whenever I press the button, the quote in the label changes to the next element in the **quotes array**.
This is the XAML file:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Font_Size.Greeting">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS = "0, 20, 0, 0"
                    Android = "30, 20, 0, 0"
                    WinPhone = "30, 0, 0, 0">
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>

        <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Text="Next"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

        <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
               Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Font is {0:0}'}"
               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

        <Slider x:Name="slider"
                BindingContext="{x:Reference label}"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                Maximum="30"
                Minimum="1"
                Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Label x:Name= "label"
               Text="{Binding Quote}"
               BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
               FontSize="{Binding Path=Value} " 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>





    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my C# file behind it:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Font_Size
{
    public partial class Greeting : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int count = 0;
        public string[] quotes = {"If I have seen further than others, it is by standing upon the shoulders of giants.",
            "I can calculate the motion of heavenly bodies, but not the madness of people.",
            "Tact is the knack of making a point without making an enemy." };


        public Greeting()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;

            slider.Value = 16;

            var x = new OnPlatform<Thickness>();
            Padding = x;

            BindingContext = this;

        }




        void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            quote = GetQuote(count);
        }

        public string GetQuote(int count)
        {
            int index = count % 3;
            string result = quotes[index];
            count++;

            return result;
        }

        int sliderValue;
        string quote;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public string Quote
        {
            get { return GetQuote(count); }
            set
            {
                quote = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(quote));
            }
        }

        public int SliderValue
        {
            get { return sliderValue; }
            set { sliderValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could improve the code like following .

#### in xaml

```
       <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Text="Next"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

        <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
               Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Font is {0:0}'}"
               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

        <Slider x:Name="slider"

                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                Maximum="30"
                Minimum="1"
                Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Label x:Name= "label"
               Text="{Binding Quote}"

               FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider} , Path=Value} " 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

#### in code behind

```
  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Quote = GetQuote(count);
    }

    public string GetQuote(int  count)
    {
        int index = count % 3;
        string result = quotes[index];
        this.count++;

        return result;
    }

    int sliderValue;
    string quote;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public string Quote
    {
        get { return GetQuote(count); }
        set
        {
            if(quote!=value)
            {
                quote = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Quote));
            }
        }
    }

    public int SliderValue
    {
        get { return sliderValue; }
        set
        {
            sliderValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

### Note:

in the method

```
public string GetQuote(int  count)
{
    int index = count % 3;
    string result = quotes[index];
    this.count++;

    return result;
}
```

If you invoke the line `count++` , it will only change the value of parameter count , the property count will never been set. So the text of label never been changed .

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in Quote property you use wrong name:

`OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Quote));`

instead of:

`OnPropertyChanged(nameof(quote));`

And on button click should be:

`Quote = GetQuote(count);`

instead of:

`quote = GetQuote(count);`

Comment: Also, setting BindingContext in xaml for every control is wrong. You already set it once in the constructor. If you want to bind to a specific property of control, from another control, just use Reference in Source for the binding of that property, no setting of BindingContext required.